# convert ip ranges list to cidr

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have file with such struct:

```
08.176.250.200-108.176.250.219
108.176.251.40-108.176.251.163
108.176.254.212-108.176.254.215
108.176.254.216-108.176.255.87
108.177.224.0-108.177.225.255
108.179.0.32-108.179.0.87
108.179.0.192-108.179.0.255
108.179.4.0-108.179.4.255
108.179.13.0-108.179.13.255
108.179.18.0-108.179.18.15
108.179.18.16-108.179.19.255
108.179.25.0-108.179.25.255
108.179.32.16-108.179.33.255
108.179.42.64-108.179.42.255
```

How can I convert them to cidr and save to new file?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`ipcalc`](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) to calculate `cidr` from IP range :

```
~/test$ ipcalc -rn 108.179.42.64-108.179.42.255
deaggregate 108.179.42.64 - 108.179.42.255
108.179.42.64/26
108.179.42.128/25
```

The following will compute the IP range for each line of your file (`ip.txt`) and store it in `cidr.txt` :

```
awk '{system("ipcalc -rn "$1 "| tail -n +2")}' ip.txt > cidr.txt
```

or with `xargs` :

```
<ip.txt  xargs -I '{}' bash -c 'ipcalc -rn {} | tail -n +2' > cidr.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure `ipcalc -rn` thing is a correct syntax? because I got error here. `ipcalc: bad IPv4 prefix: n` , and from documentation of man ipcalc, it's weird that the argument is not use to calculate range but it said: `-r, --random-private=PREFIX-Generate a random private IP network using | -n, --network-Display network address`. It's not a valid option here I think. How is that possible you got that output. What is your ipcalc version.

Comment: @MaXi32 yes, the correct syntax is: `ipcalc -d 108.179.42.64-108.179.42.255`

Comment: @MaXi32 Apparently this is [ipcalc](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ipcalc/ipcalc.1.en.html) (Website: [ipcalc](http://jodies.de/ipcalc), written in Perl) vs. [ipcalc-ng](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ipcalc-ng/ipcalc-ng.1.en.html) (Website: [ipcalc](https://gitlab.com/ipcalc/ipcalc), written in C) syntax. FWIW, Fedora just packages ipcalc-ng as ipcalc. Unfortunately, both projects share the same name and neither explains its relation nor history on its project page.

Comment: That was 3 years back and for this question I already found a way to solve it.